# Decision tree when leaf nodes are numerical values

Tags: r, cart

I'm having a dataset, where I created a decision tree. My output variables are binary values. I selected two features and the decision tree was generated using R. This is my code.

```
latlontree = rpart(Medv ~ Crim + Rm, data=housing_data)
```

Following is my decision tree

[image]

Can someone help me to interpret this decision tree with any branch
When I changed my code to following the tree changed like below

[image: latlontree = rpart(Medv ~ Crim + Rm, data=housing_data , method = "class")]

What is the difference? Is right hand side of the tree corresponding always to No?

Answer (score 0):

Right hand side always correspond to no. It means that thé first split of your tree is :

- left = observations with Rm < 6.5
- right = obs. with Rm >= 6.5

The values at the bottom of your trees correspond to leaf, and correspond to the probabilty to be Medv = 1 (for the observations that arrived until this leaf)